# Nginx as reverse proxy on docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy on a docker container. Docker should have internal DNS which resolves container names by finding their ip address.

From the Nginx container if I use `ping apache`, docker resolves the ip address and the container with apache replies.

If I use the following address, in the nginx configuration it doesn't work and I get `502 bad gateway`. I have to manually specify the ip of the docker apache container.

```
proxy_pass http://apache:8080$request_uri;
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using this line to set docker dns as resolver within nginx config.

```
resolver 127.0.0.11;
```

However I'm not sure that docker dns address won't change over time.

Comment: Are `nginx` and `apache` containers in the same **network**?

Comment: Do you run them via `docker-compose`? Or `docker run ...`?

Comment: via docker-compose

Comment: And are they in the same file? Or if they're not, did you add network part in `docker-compose` files?